# Count total users' first order for each region, each day

Tags: sql

I have a table called orders.
Link for the table here:
[table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UdgwUHtFGcb2cOzPBiAVI-hYzhyZnmAIob4HZcJ6WUw/edit?usp=sharing)

I want to get the **total users' first order in each region, each day**.
First, I tried to get: the first order for each unique user by doing this:

```
SELECT  customer_id, 
    MIN(order_date) first_buy, 
    region
FROM orders
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2, 1;
```

This resulted with:

```
customer_id, first_buy, region
BD-11500, 2017-01-02, Central
DB-13060, 2017-01-03, West
GW-14605, 2017-01-03, West
HR-14770, 2017-01-03, West
SC-20380, 2017-01-03, West
VF-21715, 2017-01-03, Central
```

And so on.
You can see there are 4 unique users on 2017-01-03 in West.
I want to get this result:

```
first_buy, region, count_user
2017-01-02, Central, 1
2017-01-03, West, 4
2017-01-03, Central, 1
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, *What do you think?* is not an acceptable question here. Your question should be clear and specific.

Comment: hey Ken White. Thanks for the advice. I shouldn't have put the last sentence there. I think I've explained my question clearly above and desired output and how I approached the question. Anyway, appreciate it

Comment: And yet the image that I explained should not be there still is there. Doesn't seem like you followed the link I posted at all.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but I think this will give what you wanting to achieve

```
SELECT first_buy, region, COUNT(customer_id) AS count_user
FROM (SELECT  customer_id, MIN(order_date) first_buy, region
      FROM orders
      GROUP BY customer_id) AS t
GROUP BY first_buy, region
```

Comment: thanks. It works. Just need to order it by first_but at the end. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
first_buy = (SELECT MIN(order_date) FROM orders WHERE orders.region = ord.region),
ord.region,
count_user = ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE orders.region = ord.region GROUP BY orders.customer_id), 0)
 FROM orders ord
GROUP BY ord.region
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the response. It helps me. I wonder if this is SQL server syntax?

Comment: Hi! You didn’t put any information about your db, I used ms sql, but this method can work on other db as well.

Comment: It works on MySQL. Sorry, forgot to mention that